# Write in append mode a file that is already written

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file already wrote ("file_wrote") at example:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

When I wish to write a line:

```
line = ["a","a","a","a","a","a"]
newline = "    ".join([str(e) for e in line]) + "\n"
with open("file_wrote", 'a') as file_out:
     file_out.write(newline)
```

I got this problem:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, a, a, a, a, a, a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a newline to the front of `newline`:

```
file_out.write("\n" + newline)
```

Otherwise, Python will write the text to the end of the last line in the file.

---

Keep in mind too that you added a newline to the end of `newline` here:

```
newline = "    ".join([str(e) for e in line]) + "\n"
#                                               ^^^^
```

This means that, when you run your code, a blank line will be added to the end of the file.  I think you might want to remove this newline:

```
newline = "    ".join([str(e) for e in line])
```